# RuntimeValueProvider in Dataflow Streaming engine, apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've noticed, that RuntimeValueProvider works in batch mode example, but in streaming mode with streaming engine, runtime parameters are not transfered to job, and error is raised

`apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: templated_int, type: int, default_value: None).get() not called from a runtime context`

Imagine simple basic setup from example in streaming mode

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--templated_int', type=int)

class MySumFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, templated_int):
        self.templated_int = templated_int

    def process(self, an_int):
        yield str(self.templated_int.get()) + str(an_int)

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)
sum = (p
     | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
            subscription=f"projects/xxx/subscriptions/yyy"
        )
     | 'AddGivenInt' >> beam.ParDo(MySumFn(user_options.templated_int)))

r = p.run()
r.wait_until_finish()
```

Half of the problem - that by default UserOptions params are discarded by pipeline on run

```
""Discarding unparseable args: ['--autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE', '--beam_plugins=apache_beam.io.filesystem.FileSystem', '--beam_plugins=apache_beam.io.hadoopfilesystem.HadoopFileSystem', '--beam_plugins=apache_beam.io.localfilesystem.LocalFileSystem', '--beam_plugins=apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem', '--beam_plugins=apache_beam.io.aws.s3filesystem.S3FileSystem', '--beam_plugins=apache_beam.io.azure.blobstoragefilesystem.BlobStorageFileSystem', '--dataflowJobId=2021-02-27_23_43_27-14526297939696446033', '--direct_runner_use_stacked_bundle', '--enableStreamingEngine', '--gcpTempLocation=gs://xxx/staging', '--job_server_timeout=60', '--maxNumWorkers=0', '--numWorkers=2', '--pipelineUrl=gs://xxx/staging/beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228074146-355878.1614498106.356068/pipeline.pb', '--pipeline_type_check', '--tempLocation=gs://rxxx/staging', '--templateLocation=gs://xxx/templates/simple-', '--templated_int=99']"
```

So, `templated_int` is discarded and doesn't get into the options

```
"Python sdk harness started with pipeline_options: {'runner': 'DataflowRunner', 'streaming': True, 'project': 'xxx', 'job_name': 'beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228074146-355878', 'staging_location': 'gs://xxx/staging/beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228074146-355878.1614498106.356068', 'temp_location': 'gs://xxx/temp/beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228074146-355878.1614498106.356068', 'region': 'europe-west2', 'template_location': 'gs://xxx/templates/simple-', 'experiments': ['use_fastavro', 'runner_harness_container_image=gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/harness:2.27.0', 'use_multiple_sdk_containers', 'enable_streaming_engine', 'use_unified_worker', 'beam_fn_api', 'use_runner_v2', 'enable_windmill_service'], 'sdk_worker_parallelism': '1', 'environment_cache_millis': '0', 'job_port': '0', 'artifact_port': '0', 'expansion_port': '0'}"
```

But you can fix this with `save_main_session`. With this flag, UserOptions is unpickled and used in run.

But still, `templated_int` param is not defined in runtime and `RuntimeValueProviderError not called from a runtime context` error is raised.
It is defined in logs as StaticValueProvider

```
"Python sdk harness started with pipeline_options: {'runner': 'DataflowRunner', 'streaming': True, 'project': 'xxx', 'job_name': 'beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228090521-088961', 'staging_location': 'gs://xxx/staging/beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228090521-088961.1614503121.089117', 'temp_location': 'gs://xxx/temp/beamapp-pavelkulikov-0228090521-088961.1614503121.089117', 'region': 'europe-west2', 'template_location': 'gs://xxx/templates/simple-', 'experiments': ['use_fastavro', 'runner_harness_container_image=gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/harness:2.27.0', 'use_multiple_sdk_containers', 'enable_streaming_engine', 'use_runner_v2', 'beam_fn_api', 'enable_windmill_service', 'use_unified_worker'], 'save_main_session': True, 'sdk_worker_parallelism': '1', 'environment_cache_millis': '0', 'job_port': '0', 'artifact_port': '0', 'expansion_port': '0', 'templated_int': <apache_beam.options.value_provider.StaticValueProvider object at 0x7f31ff7771c0>}"
```

But how to use it?

Seems that streaming engine init is differs from batch mode.
How can i use runtime param for streaming?

Comment: Are you using Dataflow [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-pipeline-options) or are you using the value provider in a normal job? It seems that your usage is passing the option at pipeline construction time, which should use StaticValueProvider, or simply pass it in like this [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py#L56).

Comment: we use templates, there are no params at construction time

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the source code of Apache Beam, i've found one workaround

All workers contains `PIPELINE_OPTIONS` env with all related options, including parameters of dataflow jobs.
It is json string, dict with this format

```json
{
    "display_data":
    [
        {
            "key": "runner",
            "namespace": "apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions",
            "type": "STRING",
            "value": "DataflowRunner"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "options":
    {
        "artifact_port": 0,
        "autoscalingAlgorithm": "NONE",
        ...
        "templated_int": "999999",
        ...
    }
}
```

Also `save_main_session` is not required for that.

So by calling `json.loads(os.environ['PIPELINE_OPTIONS'])['options']['templated_int'])` i can get my parameter, as a string.
Of course, this can be changed in the future, but it is working with apache beam 2.28